# Culpado vs Culpable - ¿cuál es la diferencia?

Tags: vocabulario, diferencias-entre-palabras

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre *culpado* y *culpable*? ¿Cuándo y cómo utilizarlas? Ya he buscado sus significados el en diccionario, pero no me quedó clara la diferencia...

Comment: "culpable" is the most usual word and the one I hear most in drug traffic series (such as Narcos) and investigation/trial movies.

Answer (score 5):

El participio pasado "culpado" se usa en la voz pasiva y en tiempos perfectos o compuestos, por ejemplo:

- Juan fue culpado de hurto. (similar a "acusado")
- María ha culpado a Juan de hurto. (ídem)

En cambio, "culpable" es un adjetivo y puede aparecer junto a un sustantivo o después de un verbo que habilite el uso de un predicativo subjetivo u objetivo. El significado es similar a "responsable de una falta / de un delito". También puede usarse como sustantivo.

- Me siento culpable. (predicativo subjetivo, porque "culpable" se refiere al sujeto "yo")
- Lo declararon culpable. (predicativo objetivo, porque "culpable" se refiere al objeto directo "él")

El participio "culpado" puede aparecer junto a un sustantivo pero normalmente antes de una frase preposicional indicativa del motivo de la acusación o del agente (la persona acusadora):

- El culpable (= la persona culpable) ha sido condenado a prisión.
- El hombre culpado de hurto resultó ser inocente.
- El hombre culpado por sus vecinos resultó ser inocente.

Nótese que quien es culpado (= acusado) de algo no es necesariamente culpable de aquello de lo que es culpado.

Answer (score 1):

si las respuestas de diccionario no te ayudaron, tal vez pueda hacerlo mas intuitivo. Imaginemos que la culpa es un objeto, como una pelota, que tienes que llevar escondida.

**El Culpado:** Este seria el que crees tu, o otros creen que tiene la culpa (La pelota).

**El Culpable:** Es el que en realidad tiene la culpa (La pelota).